# 3D object won't show up on AGOL scene viewer

Tags: arcgis-online, 3d, web-scene, scene-layer-package

I'm trying to add a 3D object that has a multipatch texture on to ArcGIS Online Scene Viewer.

It's only one object as I'm just testing it out, what I did was made a 3D feature layer and drew out a cube extruded it then I added an image as multipatch texture. Next I saved it as a layer file and then converted the layer file into a scene layer content file (slpk). However when I upload it onto ArcGIS Online and drag it into Scene Viewer nothing shows up.

I'm still new to how scene viewer works and 3D object on ArcGIS Pro so is there a better way of going about added a 3D object with a custom texture on to the maps?